# Wordpress: Redirect index(yourdomain to a page like home or yourdomain/?page_id=2

Tags: php, html, wordpress, redirect, integrate

Hi i want to Redirect my  'yourdomain'  to a page like home or  'yourdomain/?page_id=2'.
I want to make a page as welcome or home page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the given article that helps you to create a Custom Home Page. You don't have to redirect anything, just select you created page. That's it.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-homepage-in-wordpress/

Hope this what you want.